# How to get the select dropdown text instead of value using reactive form in Angular

Tags: forms, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Reactive form as shown below.

> HTML file

```
 <ion-select formControlName="gender" (ionChange)="onGenderChange($event)">
     <ion-select-option value="1">Male</ion-select-option>
     <ion-select-option value="2">Female</ion-select-option>
 </ion-select>
```

> TS File

I want to get the selected text (Male or Female) instead of its value. Below is on Change event of select dropdown.

```
  onGenderChange(event) {
    console.log("onGenderChange : ", event.detail.value); //its return only value
  }
```

Please help me to solve this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The easiest way is to set the value equal to the text. There is no obligation to use number as value  <ion-select-option value="Male">Male</ion-select-option>

Comment: value will come from the backend as number @uKioops

Comment: maybe you'll need to share an example of your data to help understand your problem. I posted an answer. I know you want to extract the text, but maybe with a different format of your data you can get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on what type of data you'll get from your backend but you can choose what to use as value and as text with data binding.

For example in my .ts page file I created this data with your function :

```
 myData = ["Testing", "Testing 2", "Testing 3"]

   onGenderChange(event) {
console.log("onGenderChange : ", event.detail.value); //its return only value
}
```

And with data biding I could use this array as I want in the .html page

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
  <ion-select formControlName="gender" (ionChange)="onGenderChange($event)">
  <ion-select-option value="{{myData[0]}}">{{myData[0]}}</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="{{myData[1]}}">{{myData[1]}}</ion-select-option>
  <ion-select-option value="{{myData[2]}}">{{myData[2]}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

and in the console you'll get *"onGenderChange :  Testing 2"*

Comment: My backend data looks like below: let list = [{id: 0, value: 'Male'}, {id: 1, value: 'Female'}]; and my select options will be in ngFor loop.
     <ion-select-option value="list.id">{{list.value}}</ion-select-option>

Comment: But do you need the id ? You said you want the value, why do you use list.id as ion-select- option value ? <ion-select-option value="list.value">{{list.value}}</ion-select-option> should work

Comment: I need to set it as id not as value coz i need to pass that selected gender id into database